# How to make new instance of the same UIViewController from within the same?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have chat functionality in iOS app , using XMPP framework.But I am stuck with implementing simultaneous chat.For example if a user is chatting with a buddy and a new message comes in from another buddy  , can I open another instance of the same Chat View controller to show that message?

This is my Chat View Controller

```
-(void)recvdMsg:(NSDictionary *)msg
{
   NSLog(@"received message : - %@" , msg);     // contains message & sender.
   NSMutableDictionary *newMsg=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   NSString *m = [msg objectForKey:@"msg"];
   [newMsg setObject:m forKey:@"message"];
    // few more lines and finally;
   [bbltblView reloadData];   // reload table view.
```

Now if message from another sender comes in, I want to navigate the user to a new ChatVC and he can come back to the current chat as well.So if....

```
  if (self.title != sender)
  {
        // navigating to another instance.
  }
```

Comment: If you want to flow like what app or other chat app. Then once New message will come and user click on the message in notification then move them to ChatView, Or if you are in Chat View and new Message came, and use tapped on new message notifiation then load sender message in chat window. Don't create any other instance of you Chat View.

Comment: You can push segue to another view controller. When you're done with the new message, you can unwind back to the previous view controller. But I don't think this is a good way. Why don't you implement some kind of "tab" mechanism in the same view controller so that you can just update the view when you change tabs?

Answer (score 0):

May be you could refresh/reload your Chat view controller by calling its  `viewDidLoad`